# Why am I getting an infinite loop with this React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a codesandbox of the problem, simplified as much as possible:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-galileo-6chlq?file=/src/index.js

In the real app I'm making `async` api calls with `axios` but that doesn't appear to be the problem.  You can see the 2 console logs are repeated until the app crashes in about 20ms...

Comment: Because you're calling `getWeather` every render, and `getWeather` sets new state, resulting in another render, etc

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own; include enough code to allow people to understand the problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand, is the code sandbox not enough to understand the problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance When should I be calling `getWeather`? Can you show me in a quick answer or in the sandbox?

Comment: Call it in a `useEffect` hook

Comment: Please use following code in useEffect to avoid recursive renders.

   

     useEffect ( () => {
        getWeather();
      });

Or


     useEffect ( () => {
        getWeather();
      },[]);

Comment: @PsiKai Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, specifically the "Help others reproduce the problem" section where it states code should be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [Updated version](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-greider-lynf1?file=/src/index.js)

You called getWeather at every render and getWeather triggers re-rendering (by updating state)
So it's an infinite loop.
To avoid it, you should run getWeather very first time only and it could be done by getEffect() hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If I wanted to call `getWeather` every 60000ms, would I use `setInterval` around the entire `getWeather` declaration or just the function call?

Comment: You can use just the function call but that setInterval should be inside useEffect hook body section too in that case.
It will be clear if you have exact understanding that whatever script outside useEffect is called at every render.